# How to swap items in treeview control?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a treeview control:

- Parent Item 1

  - Child Item 1
  - Child Item 2
  - Child Item 3
- Parent Item 2

  - Child Item 1
  - Child Item 2
  - Child Item 3
- Parent Item 3

  - Child Item 1
  - Child Item 2
  - Child Item 3

I want to move, for example ***Parent Item 2***, up or down with its child items as well as i want to move child items up/down for its parent level.

p.s. I've done this with database, but it's performance issue to rebind treeview every move operation.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a modified version of the code found <strike>[here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53)</strike> [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151107025019/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488) in the past to drag/drop UI items in a `TreeView`

Basically it finds the parent control that holds the collection, uses the ItemContainerGenerator to find the container that holds the dragged item, then moves the container to the new location within the parent control

Comment: Link no longer works, but the description is useful.

Comment: @SuLlewellyn I added a link to a cached copy of the article, glad the description helped though!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a two way binding with your custom object ? You can add a custom sorter for the treeview View model by order property for example...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't that work?

```
TreeNode node1 = treeView.Nodes[1];
TreeNode node2 = treeView.Nodes[2];
treeView.Nodes[1] = node2;
treeView.Nodes[2] = node1;
```

Comment: I've tried this but it does not works. p.s. TreeView has Items property not Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The following example is workable for me. Select a child node and swap with its parent node.

```
TreeNode currentNode, targetNode;
currentNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode;
targetNode = currentNode.Parent;
if (currentNode.Parent != null)
{
    CopyedTreeNode = (TreeNode)targetNode.Clone();
    CopyedTreeNode02 = (TreeNode)currentNode.Clone();

    targetNode.Text = CopyedTreeNode02.Text;
    targetNode.Tag = CopyedTreeNode02.Tag;
    targetNode.ImageIndex = CopyedTreeNode02.ImageIndex;
    targetNode.SelectedImageIndex = CopyedTreeNode02.SelectedImageIndex;

    currentNode.Text = CopyedTreeNode.Text;
    currentNode.Tag = CopyedTreeNode.Tag;
    currentNode.ImageIndex = CopyedTreeNode.ImageIndex;
    currentNode.SelectedImageIndex = CopyedTreeNode.SelectedImageIndex;

    CopyedTreeNode.Remove();
    CopyedTreeNode02.Remove();
}
```